# Removing items from a list based on a function

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most efficient way to remove items from a list based on a function in python (and any common library)?

For example, if I have the following function:

```
def func(a):
    return a % 2 == 1
```

And the following list:

```
arr = [1,4,5,8,20,24]
```

Then I would want the result:

```
new_arr = [1,5]
```

I know I could simply iterate over the list like such:

```
new_arr = [i for i in arr if func(a)]
```

Just wondering if this is an efficient approach (for large datasets), or if there might be a better way.  I was thinking maybe using np to map and changing the function to return a if True and -1 if false, and then using np remove to remove all 0s?

Edit:
I decided to test it myself with the suggestions you all gave (I probably just should have tested runtime myself rather than being lazy and asking other people).

`filter` was by far the fastest alone. Though if you needed a list for random access it was comparable to the `[i for i in arr if func(i)]` method.

The numpy `[np.vectorize(func)(arr)]` was slightly faster than the other list methods.

Comment: "is this an efficient approach" is a value judgement only you can make.  Since you don't know yet, you don't *quite* have a good question for Stack Overflow.  You know about other approaches -- *test* them. with `timer`.

Comment: Its almost like I made a answer about that well before you made this comment.

Comment: I now see that you did. information critical to the question belongs in the question.  As this stands, you've merely covered a topic that is handled quite thoroughly elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the use case for the builtin [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
filtered_arr = filter(func, arr)
```

Note that this returns an iterator, not a list. If you want a list, you can create one with `list(filtered_arr)` or a list comprehension as you noted. But if you just want to iterate over the filtered items and don't need random access / indexing, it's more memory efficient to use the iterator.

This is a good general approach for filtering lists that are not especially large and contain elements with arbitrary (and possibly mixed) types. If you are working with a large amount of numerical data, you should use one of the NumPy solutions mentioned in other answers.

Comment: You need to convert it to list again : `list(filter(func, arr))`

Comment: @aminrd See my edit, you should only create a list if you actually need one.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numpy tag is present, let use it. In the example we use a mask for elements that give remainder 1 when divided by 2.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> arr = np.array([1,4,5,8,20,24])
>>> arr
array([ 1,  4,  5,  8, 20, 24])
>>> arr[arr % 2 == 1]
array([1, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy you could use `numpy.vectorize` to map your function across your array elements, then use that to keep the elements that evaluate to `True`. So starting with your function

```
def func(a):
    return a % 2 == 1
```

We could test keeping only the odd values from the range of [0, 19]

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(20)
>>> arr
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
>>> np.vectorize(func)(arr)
array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True])
>>> arr[np.vectorize(func)(arr)]
array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also rewrite `func` to make it take a list as an argument:

```
def func(lst):
    lst = [x for x in lst if x % 2 == 1]
    return lst
```

and then do:

```
new_arr = func(arr)
```

This would save you some lines in comparison to making `func` take a single number as argument and writing an iteration such as `[for i in arr if func(a)]` every time you want to use it on (elements of) a list.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to test it myself with the suggestions you all gave (I probably just should have tested runtime myself rather than being lazy and asking other people).

`filter` was by far the fastest alone.  Though if you needed a list for random access it was comparable to the `[i for i in arr if func(i)]` method.

The numpy `[np.vectorize(func)(arr)]` was slightly faster than the other methods.

Just wanted to post this in case anyone else runs across this in the future.